# React Application throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", after adding lazy loading at route level

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

Application is built with CRA and the following are the version details:

React: 16.13.1
React-Scripts: 3.4.1

Getting unexpected token error after deploying app in production.
Error in prod : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
lazy load Statement : 

const Xyz = React.lazy(() =>
  import("components/XYZ/container/Index")
);


Suspense:

 <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route
                      key={index}
                      exact={route.nested ? false : true}
                      path={route.path}
                      // component={route.component}
                      render={routeProps => <Xyz {...routerProps}/>
                        
                      }
                    />
</Switch>
    </Router>
</Suspense>
```

Comment: Are you using `await` at root level? So, not inside a function?

Comment: By the way, some code is needed to understand the issue, please, update your question.

Comment: no, i am not using await 
here is the sample i am adding code for lazy load

Comment: If this is working in local but not in production, most likely you are not building the code in a proper way. With CRA, it should be enough to use the output of `yarn build` (or something similar if you are using `npm`) to deploy your code.

Comment: I am using a docker image in production and serving it using nginx
can it be solved by updating react version?